# Check for event in last x years return dummy

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to check whether an event (grouped by airline) occurred in the last 3 years (including current year). If it did, I want a 1 returned. If it didn't, I want a 0 returned. How do I do this? My data looks like this:

```
Airline          Year  Fatal  Non_Fatal
French_Airline   1989    0       1 
French_Airline   1990    1       0 
French_Airline   1991    0       0
French_Airline   1992    0       1
French_Airline   1993    0       0
UK_Airline       1989    1       1
UK_Airline       1990    0       0
UK_Airline       1991    1       0
UK_Airline       1992    0       0
UK_Airline       1993    0       0
```

My output would ideally look something like this

```
Airline          Year  Fatal  Non_Fatal Last_3_Fatal Last_3_NonFatal
French_Airline   1989    0       1            0            1
French_Airline   1990    1       0            1            1
French_Airline   1991    0       0            1            1
French_Airline   1992    0       1            1            1 
French_Airline   1993    0       0            0            1
UK_Airline       1989    1       1            1            1
UK_Airline       1990    0       0            1            1
UK_Airline       1991    1       0            1            1
UK_Airline       1992    0       0            1            0 
UK_Airline       1993    0       0            1            0
```

This is about airline crashes.

Comment: It's probably very simple, I'm just new. I'll try. Thanks!

Comment: You could easily solve this using dplyr if `lag` could accept a vector. I think there is a FR somewhere in GH. Using `data.table`, something like ```Reduce(`+`, data.table::shift(df$Fatal, 0:2, 0L))``` could bring you close too if you would pass it as a function

Comment: @ZheyuanLi Could you maybe give an example of how it would work with rollapply here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My original comment on your question:

> Isn't this just a rolling operation? You want rolling maximum. Use package `zoo`, and try `rollapply`.

---

Here is an example demonstration.

```
#install.packages("zoo")
library(zoo)
```

We look at the basic case first, where data are not grouped. Consider a toy vector:

```
set.seed(0);x <- sample(0:1,10,TRUE)
# [1] 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1
rollapply(x, max, width = 3, partial = TRUE, align = "right")
# [1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

Note that, you want `partial = TRUE` and `align = "right"` here. Read details section in `?rollapply` for more. (Also note that it is for the need of `partial = TRUE`, that we can not use `rollmax`.) For convenience, we define a wrapper function:

```
last3 <- function (u) rollapply(u, max, width = 3, partial = TRUE, align = "right")
```

For grouped data, there is nothing special but apply `rollapply` by group, for which we use `tapply` function.

```
## a data frame: two groups `a` and `b`, each with 10 data
set.seed(0)
dat <- data.frame(group = gl(2, 10, labels = letters[1:2]),
                  x = sample(0:1, 20, TRUE))

## apply `last3` to `x` by `group`, and append result to `dat`
dat$last3 <- unlist(with(dat, tapply(x, group, FUN = last3)), use.names = FALSE)
#   group x last3
#1      a 1     1
#2      a 0     1
#3      a 0     1
#4      a 1     1
#5      a 1     1
#6      a 0     1
#7      a 1     1
#8      a 1     1
#9      a 1     1
#10     a 1     1
#11     b 0     0
#12     b 0     0
#13     b 0     0
#14     b 1     1
#15     b 0     1
#16     b 1     1
#17     b 0     1
#18     b 1     1
#19     b 1     1
#20     b 0     1
```

---

In case you do not understand the description of `align` in `?rollapply`, compare the following:

```
x <- 1:10
rollapply(x, max, width = 3, partial = TRUE, align = "left")
# [1]  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 10 10
rollapply(x, max, width = 3, partial = TRUE, align = "center")
# [1]  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 10
rollapply(x, max, width = 3, partial = TRUE, align = "right")
# [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

Obviously `align = "right"` is the behaviour you hope for. (Just another comment, you can use `rollapplyr` for right alignment.)

Answer (score 2):

Using `dplyr` and `RccpRoll`, which has all sorts of window functions implemented in a very effient way your solution might be:

your data:

```
> crashes
          Airline Year Fatal Non_Fatal
1  French_Airline 1989     0         1
2  French_Airline 1990     1         0
3  French_Airline 1991     0         0
4  French_Airline 1992     0         1
5  French_Airline 1993     0         0
6      UK_Airline 1989     1         1
7      UK_Airline 1990     0         0
8      UK_Airline 1991     1         0
9      UK_Airline 1992     0         0
10     UK_Airline 1993     0         0

library(dplyr)
library(RcppRoll)
crashes %>% group_by(Airline) %>% 
  mutate(rollFatal=roll_sum(c(0,0, Fatal), 3),rollNonFatal=roll_sum(c(0,0, Non_Fatal), 3))

Source: local data frame [10 x 6]
Groups: Airline [2]

          Airline  Year Fatal Non_Fatal rollFatal rollNonFatal
            <chr> <int> <int>     <int>     <dbl>        <dbl>
1  French_Airline  1989     0         1         0            1
2  French_Airline  1990     1         0         1            1
3  French_Airline  1991     0         0         1            1
4  French_Airline  1992     0         1         1            1
5  French_Airline  1993     0         0         0            1
6      UK_Airline  1989     1         1         1            1
7      UK_Airline  1990     0         0         1            1
8      UK_Airline  1991     1         0         2            1
9      UK_Airline  1992     0         0         1            0
10     UK_Airline  1993     0         0         1            0
```

If you want `NA`s for the first 2 years by each group replace `roll_sum(c(0,0, Fatal), 3)` by `roll_sum(c(rep(NA,2), Fatal), 3)`. For rollNonFatal accordingly.

Comment: I can't find "library(RcppRoll)" this package. Any ideas?

Comment: You find the latest stable version at CRAN like most of the packages  and at [Github](https://github.com/kevinushey/RcppRoll) .